# Can multiple KafkaListener classes listen to the same topic?

Tags: spring-kafka

I have kafka topic that contains multiple events (of different types), and I'd like to handle those events in different handler classes within single application. So my question is - can I create two classes(spring components) that consumes same topic, but each of them handles different events (from that same topic)?

```
@Component
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicA")
public class SomeClass {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void handleEventA(EventA eventA) {
    }
}

@Component
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicA")
public class AnotherClass {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void handleEventB(EventB eventB) {
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void handleEventC(EventC eventC) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally you would have all the `@KafkaHandler`s in the same class.

You can do what you want, but each listener needs to be in a different consumer group and you need a default method to discard the events you are not interested in.

```java
@Component
@KafkaListener(id = "some", topics = "topicA")
public class SomeClass {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void handleEventA(EventA eventA) {
    }

    @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
    public void handleOthers(Object others) {
        // discard
    }

}

@Component
@KafkaListener(id = "another", topics = "topicA")
public class AnotherClass {

    @KafkaHandler
    public void handleEventB(EventB eventB) {
    }

    @KafkaHandler
    public void handleEventC(EventC eventC) {
    }

    @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
    public void handleOthers(Object others) {
        // discard
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just share a finding after we tried this approach, the logic of listener container is executed per `@KafkaListener` class. i.e. the associated logic of FilterStrategy and MessageConverter will be run multiple times for the same event, which is probably not what we want.