# How to call both Kafkalistener with same Topic in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I want to call two different methods with same Topic configuration.

Suppose I have Consumer project which have two different classes with same methods of kafkalistener .

Method 1 with class A :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "vijay", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consumeMethodOne(String jsonString) {
        System.out.println("ConsumerPrice1-->"+jsonString);
    }
```

Method 2 with class B :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "vijay", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consumeMethodTwo(String jsonString) {
        System.out.println("ConsumerPrice1-->"+jsonString);
    }
```

And my producer :

```
@Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
    public void send(String value) {
        kafkaTemplate.send("vijay", "This is testing producer");
    }
```

When I ran this program only one method executes so If I want to executes both methods because both have  same topics so How could I do with setting?

Comment: you mean do you want to consume same topic twice ?

Comment: Posts using the same topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59731673/can-multiple-kafkalistener-classes-listen-to-the-same-topic

Comment: @Deadpool .. yes..

Comment: What's your use case? Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @JosephRajeevMotha : I have two differn

Answer (score 0):

Consumer groups are a way of load balancing the consumers of a topic. If you have two consumers in the same group (in your case "group_id") only one of them will consume a message at a time.
Typically this would be like an application id of the consumer, and used to scale the consumer.

However, if you want two consumers and both to consume the same message you can do this by giving them two different group Id's.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "vijay", groupId = "group_id2")
    public void consumeMethodTwo(String jsonString) {
        System.out.println("ConsumerPrice1-->"+jsonString);
    }
```